# catch IndexOutOfBoundsException Exception

Tags: java

I'm trying to catch made up IndexOutOfBoundsException  error in catch block. But every time its returning -1 and not going into catch block

May I know please why its happening ? I want to reach to catch block.

```
  public class Mars {


    public int Setname(String Input) {

        int output = 0;


        try {
            output = Input.indexOf("L");
            System.out.println("Error:" + Input.indexOf("L"));

            if (output == -1){

                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
            }

        }

        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

            System.out.println("Error:2" + e.getStackTrace());
        }

        return output;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Mars O = new Mars();
        O.Setname("London");

    }

}
```

Second thing is: When we write `IndexOutOfBoundsException e` in catch block, its creating an instance of `IndexOutOfBoundsException` class ?Am I right ?

So why we can't write like in below manner ? It could be a really silly question, but just for curiosity I want to know.

```
catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e = new IndexOutOfBoundsException())
```

Comment: When we write IndexOutOfBoundsException e in catch block, its creating an instance of IndexOutOfBoundsException class ?Am I right ? no, the Exception is thrown by the code in the try block. it's in the catch, because you say: "I know this code can throw an Exception of this type" 
catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e = new IndexOutOfBoundsException()) you are not trying to create an exception, all you want to do, is handle the one that is thrown, so this is even logically incorrect

Comment: @Stultuske, please check my comment in Ayush Goyal answer..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For First Thing Mohamed Said Benmousa's answer is correct

For Second Thing

```
IndexOutOfBoundsException e
```

This doesn't create an instance . Its just a reference which is going to point on  IndexOutOfBoundsException object if thrown. Like you passed argument when calling your method.

Comment: So you mean the generated error in code is an object of type IndexOutOfBoundsException and we are pointing to that object using "IndexOutOfBoundsException e" reference. Correct ?

Comment: not really, the exception is passed to the catch block, somewhat the same way one would pass a parameter to a method

Comment: when compiler found exception it try to find the type of exeption code is generation than it throws object of that exeption like how throw keyword throw but it happened by jvm.

Comment: than the relative catch block is run . If there are more than one catch block than think of it as method overloading.

Comment: if the relative catch block not found than it try parent exception catch block.

Comment: @Stultuske, "the exception is passed to the catch block, somewhat the same way one would pass a parameter to a method" Then what's the point of creating this reference "IndexOutOfBoundsException e". Code is throwing error, and like you said that error we are passing as a parameter in catch block. Then What reference is doing if there is no object created of IndexOutOfBoundsException type ?

Comment: @Javastudent that's what we're trying to say: you are not creating anything there. you just state: "I want this to be executed if the Exception thrown is of type IndexOutOfBoundsException", and you can get the message of it from the reference

Comment: @Javastudent  even if we create object like this  catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e = new IndexOutOfBoundsException()) as you mentioned than what happen is reference will hold this object but when an exception is created jvm pass another object . Now the same reference will store the object passed by jvm and the object you made is passed for garbage collection.

Comment: @Javastudent so  this code will not throw error  but it is useless.

Comment: @AyushGoyal, so you mean to say, when error happens code looks for catch block and JVM creates an object of type IndexOutOfBoundsException.  Here error is like kind of one of the attribute of the object created by JVM. And Its JVM duty the reference we have created in catch block will point to that object which JVM have created to capture error. Does it makes sense ?

Comment: @Javastudent Exactly

Comment: @AyushGoyal, Thanks man for clearing my doubt. Its good to know how things are working actually.

Comment: @Javastudent  Please mark the useful answer and comment to verify that this question is answered and you are satisfy if you are.

Answer (score 1):

The `indexOf()` method of String returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character or `-1`, if the character does not occur. In your case, your character does not occur, that's why you are getting `-1`.

So what you should do is to force that exception like this:

```
if(output == -1){
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use an `if` statement and throw the exception

```
if(output == -1){
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException()
}
```

Comment: Its not working Ayo..!! Please check  my updated code

Comment: ?? @Javastudent  just tried it and it's entering the catch block

Comment: your example will not enter the catch block because `London` has an `L` in it. Use something that doesn't maybe `Stack` i.e `O.Setname("Stack");`

Answer (score 0):

Method `indexOf()` of String doesn't throw any exception. In fact, it returns -1 if the char you're looking for isn't in the String

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) you can check it

If you need to throw the exception, you must do something like [Ayo K](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47261508/3195314) suggested